# Money transfer from braintree account to bank account using API

Tags: node.js, braintree

I have a app, where all my money will credited to my braintree account. Now I want to transfer all my money from braintree account to my bank account using API.

APP is built in both android and ios and backend is node.js.

Can I do this? Can you give me a sample code or referral code so that I can integrate to my APP.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Braintree will automatically disburse your credit card transactions into your business bank account and there is nothing you need to do to initiate this. Most card types will be [disbursed within 2-3 business days](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/get-paid) from the date they [settle](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/transaction-lifecycle). Depending on your account type, Amex transactions can take a little longer.

PayPal transactions will automatically be disbursed into your PayPal business account.

Since Braintree automatically disburses your funds there is no way to initiate this via the API.

If you have any additional questions I would recommend contacting [Braintree Support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact) to assist you further since the funding timeline can depend on what type of account setup you have with Braintree. Our Support team should be able to review your account and give you more detailed information on what your funding timeline will be.